# CSS / Jquery Timeline / Scheduler Display

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to build a web display for scheduled events.  Each event has a dynamically calculated width (based on event duration) and margin-left (based on start time).  Each event also has a height, based on contents that need to be displayed.  Is there any simple way for me to 'move everything up', if there are no overlapping events to move the element to the top of the containing div?

I've tried putting each event in a row div, which results in a large vertical stack of events, and in columns based on the hour, which gives me event overlapping.

Normally I find my answers here, first time posting (and thus, I can't post images).  I'll provide any clarifying details as required.  Here's a link to the dev page.

```
http://198.101.211.222/index.php/matrix/dayview/2012/10/16/237
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to calculate the left edge position and right edge position for each element of one color.
then when you're placing element: set line number to 0. Then you have to look through all elements on the same line and check if either of current element's left edge or right edge is inside someone's edges. Is so you increase the line number by two and start checking again.
If no hit-on-the-same line is found - place element on the current line value